# Using accelerometer in Samsung Gear S2 in background

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, samsung-gear-s2

I'm creating a slidepresenter app that moves the slide using accelerometer. But when I move the watch its display off, and the event isn't handled. How can I get a event display off mode?

Sorry, but I forgot say I'm using Web Application Development.

Comment: Have Edited the answer for web application developement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the app being Slide Presenter the watch display should not be off while user is moving slides. I would suggest to use Power API to control the display making the app more user friendly.

**void request(PowerResource resource, PowerState state);**

**void release(PowerResource resource);**

You may use tizen.power.request() function to request the display to remain on while the app is running.

```
tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL");
```

You should consider releasing the lock before exiting from app.

```
tizen.power.release("SCREEN");
```

Add the power privilege in your config.xml file to use the Power API.

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/power"/>
```

Please check [Power State Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/device-settings-and-systems/power-states#manage) and [Power API reference](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/power.html) for details Implementation.

Comment: Once the sensor is started & callback is set, it would give data while SCREEN_NORMAL (screen is on) .

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```cpp
int ret = sensor_is_supported(SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, &supported);
if (ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE || !supported)
  return;

sensor_h sensor;
ret = sensor_get_default_sensor(SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, &sensor);
if (ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE)
  return;

ret = sensor_create_listener(sensor, &accelerometer_listener);
if (ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE)
  return;

ret = sensor_listener_set_event_cb(accelerometer_listener, 200, AccelerometerCb, nullptr);
if (ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE)
{
  sensor_destroy_listener(accelerometer_listener);
  accelerometer_listener = nullptr;
  return;
}

ret = sensor_listener_set_option(accelerometer_listener, SENSOR_OPTION_ALWAYS_ON);
if (ret != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE)
{
  // Fail to set always on
}
```

Point is [`sensor_listener_set_option`](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html#ga3c1d0ee5986bff519d76b13bbc74673f) and [`SENSOR_OPTION_ALWAYS_ON`](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html#gaf517b61e58b872f985fc2fc2a26aa56a)